# UIView does not render border as specified

Tags: ios7, rubymotion

i want to create a background view to visually group some ui elements. here is the code i use to generate the view:

```
@background = UIView.alloc.tap do |bg|
  bg.initWithFrame(CGRectMake(15, 15, view.frame.size.width - 30, 40))
  bg.layer.cornerRadius  = 5.0
  bg.layer.borderWidth   = 2.0
  bg.layer.borderColor   = Color::GRAY
  bg.backgroundColor     = Color::WHITE
  bg.autoresizingMask    = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth
end
view.addSubview @background
```

and this is the outcome

[image]

as you can see, it does not render any border. i tried various variations of using different colors and positioning the calls differently, but none of them works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the CGColor, which you can get by getting the `CGColor` property on any UIColor.

E.g.

```
bg.layer.borderColor   = UIColor.redColor.CGColor
```

Comment: thanks! i missed that detail! that is pretty terrible for a statically typed language though...